# SimpleDateFormat returns wrong date value during parse

Tags: java, android, timezone, simpledateformat

I m facing a problem:I want to get current time of GMT TimeZone in long. 
I m using the following code as given below:

```
  TimeZone timeZoneGmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
  long gmtCurrentTime = getCurrentTimeInSpecificTimeZone(timeZoneGmt);

    public static long getCurrentTimeInSpecificTimeZone(TimeZone timeZone) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    long finalValue = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSaaa");

    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);

    Date finalDate = null;

    String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    try {
        finalDate = sdf.parse(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finalValue = finalDate.getTime();
    return finalValue;
}
```

As given in, above method
while formatting
`String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());`
I m getting correct current time in GMT but as i do parsing by following code:

`finalDate=sdf.parse(date);`

Date got changed from current GMT time to 15:35:16 IST 2013 that is current time of my system.

**I tried with Calendar as well in another way:**

```
TimeZone timeZoneGmt=TimeZone.get("GMT"); 
Calendar calGmt = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calGmt.setTimeZone(timeZoneGmt); 
long finalGmtValue = 0; 
finalGmtValue = calGmt.getTimeInMillis(); 
System.out.println("Date......" + calGmt.getTime());
```

but still getting date as current time of my System Thu Jan 23 15:58:16 IST 2014 Not getting GMT current time.

Answer (score 7):

You've misunderstood how `Date` works. A `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone - if you use `Date.toString()` you'll *always* see the default time zone. The long value in a `Date` is purely the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch: it doesn't have any concept of time zone or calendar system.

If you want to represent a date and time in a particular time zone and calendar, use `Calendar` instead - but for getting "the current date and time as a long" you can just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which again does not have anything to do with the system time zone.

Additionally, even if you *did* want to do manipulation like this, you shouldn't be using string conversions. You're not *conceptually* performing any string conversions, so why introduce them?

If your aim is to display (as a string) the current date and time in a particular time zone, you should just use something like:

```
Date date = new Date(); // This will use the current time
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(...); // Pattern and locale
format.setTimeZone(zone); // The zone you want to display in

String formattedText = format.format(date);
```

When working with date and time APIs - particularly bad ones like the Java `Calendar`/`Date` API - it's *very* important that you understand exactly what each value in your system represents.

Comment: I want current date of a particular time zone in long.That is the reason,i m parsing date String.

Comment: @user1862243: What do you expect that `long` value to be? Because as I say, the *normal* meaning of a `long` with respect to date/time values in Java is "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" which has **no concept** of a time zone. What are you planning on doing with that value?

Comment: @user1862243: Edit your attempts into your question rather than adding them as comments, but I think you've fundamentally misunderstood the data types you're using. Please include in your question what you're intending to do with the `long` afterwards.

Comment: @user1862243: As I said 5 minutes ago, edit your code into the question... but I don't think you've really read my answer thoroughly. I've explained why you got that result - `Date.toString()` *always uses the current time zone*. The time zone isn't part of the `Date`. I'm not sure how many other ways I can say it...

Comment: Sorry i just added code in question.I got about Date as default time Zone.Thanks for reply.

Comment: @user1862243: That still leaves the question of what you intend to do with the `long` - and indeed what bigger problem you're trying to solve in the first place. I strongly suspect you're making your life far more complicated than it needs to be. Have you fully read my answer and now understand it?

Comment: Hey,i dont have much idea about date formatting.I already mentioned i got your point that Date use current time zone.There is nothing as such for setting timezones in Date.

Answer to your question:  what you intend to do with the long?
I need to add Current Date of GMT time Zone(in long milliseconds) to another date of different time zone(in long milliseconds).

Comment: @kittu: It's not that "Date use current time zone" - it's that calling `Date.toString()` uses the current time zone. As for adding two dates together - that makes no sense. You *can't* add dates together - it just isn't a logical operation. What's "June 10th 2013 + February 1st 2014" for example? You should clarify your actual requirements in the question.